# Passing a list of Lamba expressions for accessing Properties

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda

I have a static function today that I pass a Property expression and I create a string from it:

```
public static string SomeFunction<TModel, TProperty>(TModel model, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression){...}
```

I'd like to change it to process a list of expressions like this:

```
static string SomeFunctionForList<TModel, TProperty>(TModel model, List<Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>> expressions){...}
```

In the second case, I'd loop through the expressions and perform whatever logic I'm doing on them.

This is how I call the function now:

```
SomeFunction(this, m => m.nameOfProperty)
```

How would I call this function and define a list of the expressions?  I am trying this but it isn't working:

```
SomeFunctionForList(this,
                    new List<Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>> {
                        { m => m.nameOfProperty1},
                        { m => m.nameOfProperty2} 
});
```

I'm getting a compiler error that TModel and TProperty cannot be found.  To be clear, this is called in a different file.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I mean "TModel" and "TProperty" are not types. They are generic parameters. You have to replace "TModel" with any model type and "TProperty" with any property type.

Comment: The problem you have is that `TProperty` is going to be different for each property right?

Comment: yeah - basically, I want to send in one model and a list of lamba expressions and have the method do its magic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have generic method `SomeFunctionForList` with generic type parameters `TModel` and `TProperty`. In first case type inference is able to infer types of these parameters from first and second arguments of method call. That's why you can skip specifying type arguments explicitly.

But type inference works only for generic methods. It will not work for inference of type parameters from constructor argument. That's why you should specify `List<T>` generic argument explicitly. Note: you should specify type names instead of generic parameters. E.g. if `TModel` is `YourModel` class, and both properties have `string` type, then method call should look like:

```
SomeFunctionForList(this,
           new List<Expression<Func<YourModel, string>>> {
                    { m => m.nameOfProperty1},
                    { m => m.nameOfProperty2} 
           });
```

So, usage of list constructor is not an option here if you want to use type inference. You can use `params` to specify the variable number of arguments (which are passed as an array) and have benefits of type inference:

```
public static string SomeFunction<TModel, TProperty>(
    TModel model, params Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>[] expressions)
```

Then method call will look like

```
SomeFunctionForList(this,
              m => m.nameOfProperty1,
              m => m.nameOfProperty2
           );
```

Note that properties should have same type.

Comment: Gotcha - in real life I have several parameters after those in the method so params isn't an ideal option.  Is there any way to trick the compiler into skipping type inference?

Comment: @Corez you can't use constructor - type inference will not work here. You can create factory which creates list for you via generic method. Same approach is used with tuples - instead of calling `new Tuple<int,string>(4,"foo")` you can call factory method `Tuple.Create(4,"foo")`. Your factory can be simple as `public static List<T> CreateList<T>(params T[] items) => items.ToList();` and usage will be `SomeFunctionForList(this, Factory.CreateList(m => m.nameOfProperty1,m => m.nameOfProperty2))`

Answer (score 1):

"TModel" and "TProperty" are generic parameters and not types. But if you want to call it, you must enter any model type and any property type.

For example, this should work:

```
private string aStringProperty { get; set; }  
private int aIntegerProperty { get; set; }
```

-

```
SomeFunctionForList(this, new List<Expression<Func<Program, dynamic>>>{
                                                              { m => m.aStringProperty},
                                                              { m => m.aIntegerProperty}
                                                          });
```

In my case, I used a dynamic as property. With that you can use different types of properties, but carefully with that!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the type parameters, for example:

```
SomeFunctionForList(t,
                new List<Expression<Func<Thing, string>>> {
                    { m => m.StringProperty1},
                    { m => m.StringProperty2}
});
```

However, this only lets you use properties that all return the same type, in this case `string`. You could use `object` instead:

```
SomeFunctionForList(t,
                new List<Expression<Func<Thing, object>>> {
                    { m => m.StringProperty},
                    { m => m.BoolProperty}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string SomeFunction<TModel, TProperty>(TModel model, params Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>[] expressions)
```

Comment: I should have been more clear - I mean that the issue is occurring when I call the function.  In that file, it doesn't recognize TModel and TPropoerty

Comment: you have to unwrap the methods and use reflection the figure out the generic parameters in order to successfully invoke them. 
It's hard to guess the error without the method source code. But i think you should be able to do it via reflection.

Comment: The error is a compilation error where the caller won't compile because TModel and TProperty can't be found.  Obviously, because they're generics outside the scope of the calling code.

Comment: public static object SomeFunction<TModel, TProperty>(TModel model, params Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>[] expressions)
 => expressions.Select(e=>(e.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression).Member...);